# Switch statements in C: variable in case?

Tags: c, switch-statement, compiler-construction

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char a = 'c';
    switch('c'){
        case a:
            printf("hi\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above won't compile for this error:

```
case label does not reduce to an integer constant
```

Why is this not allowed?

Comment: I think you can only use constants inside `switch` - see http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson5.html, second example.

Comment: @Jonny: I believe he is aware of that. He's asking why that is the case -- why was C designed to only allow constants?

Answer (score 6):

The compiler is explicitly allowed to use an efficient binary tree or a jump table to evaluate case statements.

For this reason, case statements are compile time constants.

Answer (score 5):

Think about, what if you had the following:

```
int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;

switch (a)
{
case b: return 1;
case c: return 2;
}
```

What would it return?

The case labels need to be constant so that the compiler can prove that there are no ambiguities.

Comment: The 'design principle' of C is 'I'll have none of that wishy-washy runtime fluff' ;)

Comment: It won't hurt even if `b` equals to `c`,just first come,first match.

Comment: @Delan Azabani ,yeah,but what's the rationale ?

Comment: @Je Rog: That would resolve the ambiguity, but (at least in my opinion) that would be quite confusing.

Comment: Actually I have a serials of such doubt,and I think Knuth must be trading off with something(in this specific case,allowing variable for `case` won't even bring performance issue IMO), so I want to understand the design principle.

Comment: @Je Rog: What's Knuth got to do with anything? He didn't invent C. Have you been reading too much altdevblogaday? :-)  http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/04/01/the-radical-optimizationist%E2%80%99s-war-on-abstraction-and-patterns/

Comment: Sorry,then do s/Knuth/C's designer :)

Comment: It would be *incredibly* bizarre for a language to treat the switch cases as an if/else if chain (i.e. what's necessary for "first come, first match") and then *also* implement fall-through of cases.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a `switch` statement is that the compiler can produce code that only inspects the `switch` expression at run time and by that deduces the location to jump to.

If the `case` label could be expressions that are not constant, it would have to evaluate all such `case` expressions to see if there is one that matches. So instead of evaluating one expression, it would have to evaluate `n` expressions, where `n` is the number of `case` labels for that `switch`.

The whole idea of the `switch` is to do it the other way round than you did. Put the varying expression `a` in the `switch` itself, and put constants such as your `'c'` in the case.

Answer (score 2):

The C99 standard says this (and the C89 standard was very similar):

> #### §6.8.4.2 The switch statement
>
> Constraints
>
> ¶1 The controlling expression of a switch statement shall have integer type.
>
> [...]
>
> ¶3 The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of
> the case constant expressions in the same switch statement shall have the same value
> after conversion. There may be at most one default label in a switch statement.

That's the language requirement: case labels shall be integer constant expressions, and all the cases in a single switch shall be unique.  That is the way C was designed.  It is very unlikely to change now (even though the change would not break any currently valid code, or even change its meaning).

Comment: I think the meaning of the question is "Why was C designed that way?".